# Selecting matching rows from tables in join with values from either table matching a condition

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

**THE SCENARIO**

Three tables:

- orders
- customers
- delivery_addresses

**THE RELATIONS**

- **orders**.customerId points to **customers**.id
- **orders**.customerId points to **delivery_addresses**.customerId

**THE GOAL**

Is to select any items from **orders** which meet a condition of a column in **either** **customers** or **delivery_addresses**. In a more practical sense: i want to search for orders of customers with a certain name (or zip code or whatever) stored in **either** **customers** or **delivery_addresses**.

**MY ATTEMPTS**

I am not very good with joins and the logic behind them, but after some solid research i came up with this:

`SELECT orders.* FROM orders INNER JOIN customers ON orders.customerId = customers.id INNER JOIN delivery_addresses ON orders.customerId = delivery_addresses.customerId WHERE ((customers.first_name LIKE "%max%") OR (delivery_addresses.first_name LIKE "%max%"))`

This, however, does not work. I am only getting results if there is a corresponding entry in **delivery_addresses**, but not if there is only one in **customers**.

Thus, if i shorten the query like this:

`SELECT orders.* FROM orders INNER JOIN customers ON orders.customerId = customers.id WHERE (customers.first_name LIKE "%max%")`

I do get the correct results.

**CONCLUSIONS**

I am certain that i am missing a crucial point in regard to my understanding of how joins work. But i cannot figure out what it is.

Comment: You can use `Left/Right` joins. `Inner` join returns data that exists on both tables.

Comment: Thank you for the hint! But since i have two joins in the statement, which one should be which in the given case? Or is perhaps a FULL JOIN the answer?

Comment: You should change both of them to `LEFT JOIN`. Like this, you'll return all the orders and the related datafrom `customer` and `delivery_addresses`. This is a first collection, after that, using the ``WHERE` clause, you can filter the results on return orders that match you conditions.

Comment: Got it – thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `INNER JOIN` works like a filter

```
SELECT orders.* 
FROM orders 
INNER JOIN customers ON orders.customerId = customers.id 
INNER JOIN delivery_addresses ON orders.customerId = delivery_addresses.customerId 
WHERE ((customers.first_name LIKE "%max%") 
  OR (delivery_addresses.first_name LIKE "%max%"))
```

It could be rewritten using `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT orders.* 
FROM orders 
INNER JOIN customers ON orders.customerId = customers.id 
LEFT JOIN delivery_addresses ON orders.customerId = delivery_addresses.customerId 
WHERE customers.first_name LIKE '%max%'
   OR delivery_addresses.first_name LIKE'%max%
```

Alternatively using `UNION`:

```
SELECT orders.* 
FROM orders 
INNER JOIN customers ON orders.customerId = customers.id 
WHERE customers.first_name LIKE '%max%'
UNION
SELECT orders.* 
FROM orders 
INNER JOIN customers ON orders.customerId = customers.id 
INNER JOIN delivery_addresses ON orders.customerId = delivery_addresses.customerId 
WHERE delivery_addresses.first_name LIKE'%max%
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `LEFT` joins and all the conditions in the `ON` clauses:

```
SELECT o.* 
FROM orders o 
LEFT JOIN customers c ON o.customerId = c.id AND c.first_name LIKE "%max%"
LEFT JOIN delivery_addresses d ON o.customerId = d.customerId AND d.first_name LIKE "%max%"
WHERE c.id IS NOT NULL OR d.customerId IS NOT NULL
```

You may have to add `DISTINCT` after `SELECT` if you are getting duplicate rows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.*
....................
```

Comment: What is the difference in this case, if i place the conditions in the ON clauses?

Comment: If you set the conditions c.first_name LIKE "%max%" and d.first_name LIKE "%max%" in the WHERE clause then you are actually doing INNER joins so you will get only orders where the first_name matches in both customers and delivery_addresses which is not what you want. In your case you want at least 1 match. This is why the only condition needed in the WHERE clause is `c.id IS NOT NULL OR d.customerId IS NOT NULL`

Comment: I am not sure why, but i implemented this without moving the conditions as said, and it works great, even when combined with three or four different tables, even though then the trick was to work with different logics (OR/AND) when combining the WHERE clause. But thank you for your help! All comments and posts have been very helpful in getting where i need to go.